# Python Heap Sort is changing numbers to 0 instead of sorting them

Tags: python

My professor gave us some code to implement heapsort into our sorting class, and I can't seem to get it to work right. Every time I print it out, some of the numbers are converting into 0 (or 1s with a random fill) and not getting sorted. I know this because I have a fill function that just creates an array of numbers with increasing value that it is supposed to sort.

```
def heapsort(self):
    n = self.size  # Doing this for simplicity

    for k in range((n-2) // 2, -1, -1):
        self.downheap(n, k)

    for m in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
        self.data[m], self.data[0] = self.data[0], self.data[m]
        self.downheap(m, 0)

    def downheap(self, n, k):
        if n > 1:
            key = self.data[k]
            isHeap = False

            while (k <= (n-2) // 2) and not isHeap:
                j = 2 * k + 1
                if j + 1 < n:
                    if self.data[j] < self.data[j + 1]:
                        j += 1
                if key >= self.data[j]:
                    isHeap = True
                else:
                    k = j
            self.data[k] = key
```

Unsorted list looks like-

```
 17  19   8   8   9   3  17  13   9   1 
 14  19  15  12  19   4  12   6   1   8 
 13   8  10   5   6   6   9  17   6   5 
 12   5   7  16   9  10  11   3  10  14 
  5   3  12   1   3  10  18  10   4  19 
  5  10  14   9  16   8   3  14   4  13 
 12   8  13  10  16  17  16  10  11   3 
 16   9   3  16  15   3   2  11  15   3 
  3   3  18   7   9   6  10   4   1   4 
 15  10   9   1   2  18  14  11   4   3
```

"sorted" list looks like-

```
  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 
  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   8  13 
  1   3   5   6   6   9  12   6   5  12 
  1   1   3   3   1   1   3  10   8   5 
  3  12   1   1   1   1  10   4   3   5 
 10   6   9   9   8   3   6   4   5  12 
  8   8   1   2   1   2   3   3   2   1 
  9   3  11   6   3   2   1  10   3   3 
  3   5   7   3   6   1   1   1   4   3 
  1   1   1   2  10   5   4   4   3  17
```

And here's what it does to the inc. numbers-

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
 10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19 
 20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29 
 30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39 
 40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49 
 50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59 
 60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69 
 70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79 
 80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89 
 90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 


"Sorted"

  0   0   3   4   0   0   7   8   9  10 
 11  12   0   0  15  16  17  18  19  20 
 21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28   0   0 
 31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40 
 41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  24 
 51  25  12   5  55  27  13  28  59  29 
  0   0  63  31  15  32  67  33  16   7 
 71  35  17  36  75  37   3   8  79  39 
 19  40  83  41  20   9  87  43  21  44 
 91  45   4   1  95  47  23  48  11   0
```

I've been pouring over this the last couple of days, I know I wrote everything down correctly, and I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use much smaller inputs and use a debugger; `[1, 2]` turns into `[1, 1]`, try to trace that.

Comment: (hint: `downheap()` takes `key = self.data[k]`, then alters `k` and uses `self.data[k] = key`. What happened to the old value at `self.data[k]`?)

Comment: The old value is stored at key right after the n > 1 if statement, correct?

Comment: No, `key` is the value at position A. You then manipulate `k` so you end up assingning to position B; the value that was there before is now gone.

Comment: You need to find a good description of what the shift-down function should do and test that yours does the same. Right now it doesn’t.

Comment: See http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~boyd/331/heaps.html; you are not exchanging the values at k and j

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

I had to put -
self.data[k] = self.data[j]
over k = j